# MacOS host microphone not working on WindowsXP guest VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, mac, virtualbox, audio, microphone

I need my guest Windows XP to work with the host MacOS's microphone. It all seems to be configured properly, but no audio is captured by XP. Why is that?

System Configuration:

- Host: MacOS 10.7.4
- Guest: Windows XP
- VirtualBox: 4.2.4 r81684

The virtual machine is configured to use Host Audio Driver "Core Audio", Audio Controller "ICH AC97". Inside the guest OS, I see from the Control Panel under Hardware that everything is working (no warning signs for any driver). I have also checked all volumes as per this thread [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=47277). Though, when I test Control Panel > Sounds And Audio Devices > Voice > Test Hardware, the microphone is not picking any noise. Other programs are not capturing any noise as well. Why is that?

Any help is very much appreciated!